# Proof of the set identity $(A \cap B) \cup C=A \cap(B \cup C) \iff C \subseteq A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am sorry if this question might be too trivial, but this is the first time I have to do a set identity proof.
 Prove that : $$(A \cap B) \cup C=A \cap(B \cup C) \iff C \subseteq A$$
My attempt:
Lets assume the left side as true. In order to prove $C \subseteq A$ we need to prove that if $x \in C     \Rightarrow x\in A $
Let $ x\in C$. Therefore $x \in (A \cap B) \cup C$. From $(A \cap B) \cup C=A \cap(B \cup C)$ follows that $x\in A \cap(B \cup C) \Rightarrow x \in A.$
I am not sure if that's correct though, I would appreciate feedback. 
For the other way we assume that $C \subseteq A.$
Now $(A \cap B) \cup C=(A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C) $ But $C \in A \Rightarrow (A \cup C)=A \Rightarrow (A \cap B) \cup C=A \cap(B \cup C)$.

Comment: That's perfect. No arguments on that one. What about the other way? Have you thought about it?

Comment: $(A\cap B)\cup C=(A\cup C)\cap(B\cup C)$.

Comment: Fei Li means that $(A\cap B)\cup C = (A\cup C)\cap (B\cup C)$ by distribution, and $A\cap (B\cup C)=(A\cap B)\cup(A\cap C)$ likewise.  We also know that $C\subseteq A$ means both $A=A\cup C$ and $C=A\cap C$.  So if $C\subseteq A$, then....

Comment: Much of elementary set theory is analogous to simple claims in logic. Notice that the 'or' and 'and' symbols look kind of like set unions and intersections, but pointy. Try reading these in words, and see if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\wedge$ stands for "and".

Let $C \subseteq A$. We will first show that $(A \cap B) \cup C \subseteq A \cap (B \cup C)$, then  we will show that $A \cap (B \cup C) \subseteq (A \cap B) \cup C$. This will prove the equality.

Then note that if $x \in (A \cap B) \cup C$, then either $x \in A \wedge x \in B$, or $x \in C$.

If $x \in A \wedge x \in B$, then $x \in A \wedge x \in B \cup C$, so $x \in A \cap (B \cup C)$.

If $x \in C$, then $x \in A$, so $x \in A \wedge x \in C$, hence $x \in A \wedge x \in B \cup C$, so $x \in A \cap (B \cup C)$.

Either way,$(A \cap B) \cup C \subseteq A \cap (B \cup C)$.

The other way, note that if $x \in A \cap (B \cup C)$, then $(x \in C \text{ or } x \in B) \wedge x \in A$.

If $x \in C$, then $x \in (A \cap B) \cup C$.

If $x \in B$, then $x \in A \wedge x \in B$, hence $x \in (A \cap B) \cup C$.

Either way,$ A \cap (B \cup C) \subseteq (A \cap B) \cup C $.

Hence the proposition follows.

An easier way is to notice that $(A \cap B) \cup C =  (A \cup C) \cap (B \cup C)$, and see that $A \cup C = A$ if $C \subseteq A$.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument in the forward direction looks good! Now for the backward direction try using some of the distributive identities of intersections and unions.

Comment: I added the backward in my post

Comment: Looks good. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

Following is an alternative proof using [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra) and the [Indicator functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function) $a, b, c$ of sets $A, B, C$. The equality on the left hand translates to:

$$
\begin{align}
a \times b + c - a \times b \times c & = a \times (b + c - b \times c) \\
& = a \times b + a \times c - a \times b \times c
\end{align}
$$

or, after canceling out the identical terms:
$$
c = a \times c
$$

which is equivalent to $c \leq a$ which is in turn equivalent to $C \subseteq A$.

Answer (score 0):

**Algebraic Proof**

Let $1_X$ be the indicator function of a set $X$; that is, $1_X(x)=1$ if $x\in X$, and $1_X(x)=0$ otherwise.  We have $$1_{(A\cap B)\cup C}=1_{A\cap B}+1_C-1_{A\cap B\cap C}=1_A\cdot 1_B+1_C-1_{A}\cdot 1_B\cdot 1_{ C}$$
and
$$1_{A\cap(B\cup C)}=1_A\cdot 1_{B\cup C}=1_A\cdot\left(1_B+1_C-1_{B\cap C}\right)=1_A\cdot \left(1_B+1_C-1_B\cdot 1_C\right)\,.$$
Hence, $(A\cap B)\cup C=A\cap(B\cup C)$ if and only if
$$1_A\cdot \left(1_B+1_C-1_B\cdot 1_C\right)=1_A\cdot 1_B+1_C-1_{A}\cdot 1_B\cdot 1_{ C}\,,$$
or $$1_{A\cap C}=1_A\cdot 1_C=1_C\,.$$
However, the last condition is equivalent to saying that $A\cap C=C$, which is the same as $A\supseteq C$.

**P.S.**  Just found out that dxiv offered the same solution.